# using java variable within javascript - webDriver

Tags: javascript, java, for-loop

The alert is printing `[object]` and not the value of `elemID` for each iteration.

```
for (WebElement el : listOfElem){
    String elemID = el.getAttribute("id");
    Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor) driver;
    String strg = (String) js.executeScript("alert("+elemID+");");
}
```

I also tried the code below:

```
String strg = (String)js.executeScript("alert("+elemID+");").toString();
```

This prints `[object]` too (just a note: using `toString()` breaks the loop, not sure why)

How can I print the value of `elemID` in each iteration?

If I print `elemID` outside of JavaScript, it prints the value but I want it inside of JavaScript.

---

EDIT:
If I do

```
for (WebElement el : listOfElem){
    String elemID = el.getAttribute("id");
    System.out.println(elemID);
    Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor) driver;
    String strg = (String) js.executeScript("alert("+elemID+");");
    System.out.println(strg);
}
```

It prints value for the 1st System.out correctly but the rest of the iterations prints `null`

If I use below as suggested in comments

`String strg = (String) js.executeScript("console.log("+elemID+");");` in the above edited code

It prints the value (1st Sys.out) and thats it, after that it breaks the loop and comes out.

Comment: I believe you mean `"alert("+elemID+");").toString();`

Comment: Your quotes are unbalanced.

Comment: Your code have syntax errors. First, fix that

Comment: `Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor) driver` doesn't have a semicolon

Comment: And FYI, `alert()` returns `undefined` in JS.

Comment: It may be that the problem is in how you build the listOfElem. The ID property may be set incorrectly?

Comment: I know that is a little ortodox but you can try with this `elemID.attr('id')`

Comment: I think the value is there but when I print it inside JavaScript , prints `null` or `[object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking for the answer , I got it working with:

```
for (WebElement el : listOfElem){
    String elemID = el.getAttribute("id");
    System.out.println(elemID); //1st
    Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor) driver;
    Object strg = js.executeScript("return(arguments[0]);",elemID);
    System.out.println(strg); //2nd
}
```

The above prints,in each iteration, the value of `elemID` in 2nd Sys.out statement , which is from javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `toString()` directly on `elemID`.

Please try the following code:

```
for (WebElement el : listOfElem){
    String elemID = el.getAttribute("id");
    Javascriptexecutor js = (Javascriptexecutor) driver;
    String strg = (String) js.executeScript("alert("+elemID.toString()+");");
}
```

Comment: same result , `toString()` directly on `elemID` prints  `[object]`

Comment: Can you print elemID? Don't use alert, just print it to the console. It would also help if you uploaded all of your code

Comment: Maybe only the first object in `listOfElem` actually contains something therefore the rest just print null?

Comment: All objects have values because as I stated above  "prints value for 1st System.out and for 2nd it prints null in each iteration"  . the 2nd one is to print from JS

Comment: which part are you interested in ,  to get more insight ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177379/discussion-between-james-and-user1207289).